# file management controls

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, ftp

so i'm looking for a way to allow users the ability to manage static files in their own directories on my webserver without giving them ftp access. I've seen controls like the one [here](http://www.gleamtech.com/products/filevistacontrol/asp-net-file-manager-control) that does what i want, however i'd like to weigh a few options. any recommendations?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you want to use FTP? It's a perfectly practical tool for managing static files. There are free FTP serversr available and plenty of tutorials for setting them up.

Comment: ftp isn't a good fit for some of my users. there's also the overhead of integrating ftp users into the application, i don't want to do it. i'm looking for a web based control in order to tie it into my role based security so that i can just give users roles and allow the rest of my application security to determine if they have the rights to a folder. ftp also increases overhead on managing which folders they are allowed to access.

Comment: So these static files (and their permissions) are part of the application?

Comment: right, the application controls who has access to which directories. if the mapping between directories and users was static and 1:1 i would be more inclined to use and ftp account.

Comment: If your application used Unix accounts for users, this would be possible. What does your application do by the way?

Answer (score 0):

I would refer a [chroot](http://linux.derkeiler.com/Mailing-Lists/Fedora/2005-04/2232.html) environment [minus shell](http://www.faqs.org/docs/securing/chap29sec295.html), but then it turns out you are referring to a ASP.Net manager... so, you may need a different reference. This is here for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a really good and free php script which doest use ftp (i think). its got heaps of features like ajax and it has a really nice design

http://ecosmear.com/relay/

Answer (score 0):

this is the perfect place to use an MVC pattern. don't give the user direct acces to their files on your server. instead use a controller to get a list of available files and return thier names. then give them a list of things they can do with each file/directory.

in the presentaion/view layer you can design it to make it look like the user is browsing through regular directories.